# Error when attempting to change value of float?

Tags: c++

Trying to change the value of a certain float which is used to define the RGBA of an element. The problem is when I try to change the value of the float an error occurs. Here's an example:

```
float ColorForScrollbar[4] = {1,0,0,.8};
// Set the value for ColorForScrollbar

ColorForScrollbar[4] = {0,1,0,.8};
// "Error: Expected an expression"


ColorForScrollbar = {0,1,0,.8};
// "Error: Expression must be a modifiable value"
```

Comment: Use `std::copy()` or `std::array<float,4> ColorForScrollbar;`

Comment: If you declare `ColorForScrollbar[4]`, the valid indexes are `0`-`3`, so `ColorForScrollbar[4]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float ColorForScrollbar[4] = {1,0,0,.8};
```

This is valid. The `{1,0,0,.8}` is an *initializer*. It is not, however, an expression. It can only be used after the `=` in an object declaration.

```
ColorForScrollbar[4] = {0,1,0,.8};
```

*If* this were legal, then it would (attempt to) change the value of `ColorForScrollbar[4]`, not of the entire array. Since the only elements that exist have indices 0, 1, 2, and 3, this would have undefined behavior. But again, `{0,1,0,.8}` is not an expression, so it can't be used on the RHS of an assignment.

This is closer, but it has the same problem as before. Furthermore, there is no assignment operator for array types.

You can change one element at a time:

```
ColorForScrollbar[0] = 0;
ColorForScrollbar[1] = 1;
ColorForScrollbar[2] = 0;
ColorForScrollbar[3] = 0.8;
```

Or, if you want to use the initializer syntax, you can use a temporary object:

```
#include <cstring>

const float new_value[4] = { 0, 1, 0, 0.8 };
std::memcpy((void*)ColorForScrollbar, (void*)new_value), sizeof ColorForScrollbar);
```

However, this is all rather low-level. You're probably better off using one of the C++ container classes from the standard library. Which one is best (`std::vector`, `std::array`) probably depends on just what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

An array is really just an address for a contiguous, fixed, area of memory. You can't change it any more than you can change your own street address (unless you move, of course).

What you can change, though, are the contents of an array:

```
ColorForScrollbar[0]=0;
ColorForScrollbar[1]=1;
ColorForScrollbar[2]=0;
ColorForScrollbar[3]=.8;
```

You don't have to change every value in the array, just what you need to change.

You can also do an explicit copy:

```
float NewColorForScrollBar[4] = {0,1,0,.8};

for (i=0; i<4; ++i)
    ColorForScrollbar[i]=NewColorForScrollbar[i];
```

Comment: An array is not an address.